# Set selected value on dropdown populated from database in php

Tags: php, mysql

Basically I'm working on a student database and have the following issue:
When the student form loads, it loads all the student names into a select list. From there I would to display the student detail whenever I select a student from the list. Below is what I have so far, but when I click on an item in the list, it just stays on one name, or the -- Select Student -- option, but does show the student info underneath.

Here is what I have so far.

```
<form name="list_student" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
<p><select name="names[]">
    <option>--- Select Student ---</option> 
    <?php $students = list_students();
       foreach ($students as $student){
       echo '<option  value="'.$student['studentID'].'"  onclick="document.forms.list_student.submit()"> '.$student['firstName'].'</option>';
    }
    ?>
        </select>
</form>
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']==='POST') {

    foreach($_POST['names'] as $selectedOption){

    $student = get_student($selectedOption);
    echo "Student Name : ".$student['firstName']." ".$student['lastName']."<br />";
    echo "Address : ".$student['address']."<br />";
    echo "Telephone : ".$student['telephone']."<br />";
    echo "E-mail Address : ".$student['email']."<br />";
    echo $student['studentID'];

    }
}
?>
```

I'm really hoping someone can help me.
Thank You.

Comment: What is your question then?

Comment: I need for whatever selection I make to show in the dropdown, and not jump to the default option everytime I pick an item from the list.

Comment: Problem is I need to show student Info, such as firstname, lastname, address and such for the selected student below the dropdown in a div container.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the onchange event on the select rather than the onclick event on every option.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the select box isn't a multi drop-down. Make the following alteration to your code:

```
echo '<option' .$_POST[names][0] ==$student['studentID']?  'selected': ''. ' value="'.$student['studentID'].'" onclick="document.forms.list_student.submit()"> '.$student['firstName'].'</option>'
```

You just need to add the `selected` attribute to the selected option. Please note my code might not run for you exactly as I've assumed some values in your code, but you can yet the idea of what you need.